# Is Random.NextBytes biased?

Tags: c#, random

The .NET reference source shows [the implementation of `NextBytes()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,04910e5e5c6c9a8b) as:

```
for (int i=0; i<buffer.Length; i++)
{
    buffer[i]=(byte)(InternalSample()%(Byte.MaxValue+1)); 
}
```

`InternalSample` provides a value in [0, int.MaxValue), as evidenced by it's doc comment and the fact that `Next()`, which is documented to return this range, simply calls `InternalSample`.

My concern is that, since `InternalSample` can produce `int.MaxValue` different values, and that number is not evenly divisible by 256, then we should have some slight bias in the resulting bytes, with some values (in this case just 255) occurring less frequently than others.

My question is:

1. Is this analysis correct or is the method in fact unbiased?
2. If the bias exists, is it strong enough to matter for any real application?

FYI I know `Random` should not be used for cryptographic purposes; I'm thinking about it's valid use cases (e. g. simulations).

Comment: `int.MaxValue` ** +1 ** values - did you forget zero?

Comment: Hmm, no, this is a biased analysis.  The operation simply takes the low 8 bits of the value.  The range 0..int.maxvalue has an integer multiple of 256 values, 8,388,608 of them.  No bias, Donald made sure.

Comment: @AndrewMorton [the docs for Random.Next()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b3ta19y(v=vs.110).aspx) seem to suggest that the int.MaxValue can never be returned. Hence we have `int.MaxValue` values, not `int.MaxValue + 1` values, right?

Comment: @HansPassant is your range inclusive of `int.MaxValue` or exclusive? I'm assuming (based on the docs and comments in the source) that `InternalSample` cannot return `int.MaxValue`. Look at the two if statements that prevent this in the [InternalSample source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,e137873446fcef75)

Comment: Actually I think there's a possible bias in the MS implementation, especially in this line in the implementation of InternalSample(): `if (retVal == MBIG) retVal--;`, where `MBIG` is `int.MaxValue`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I agree that that line seems quite sketchy, and likely to make int.MaxValue - 1 twice as likely to show up. I don't know enough about the subtractive generator to say for sure, though. I do not see that line in the [referenced implementation](http://www2.units.it/ipl/students_area/imm2/files/Numerical_Recipes.pdf) (pg 283).

Comment: In any case the `Next()` method *is* biased. The `Random` class is not the nicest thing in the BCL.

Comment: After waiting for rand.Next() to turn up Int32.MaxValue and not doing so, although Int32.MaxValue-(1..10) did turn up more than once while waiting, I have to agree that there is not even some sneaky way, despite the published code, that Int32.MaxValue would be returned.

Comment: Why not use the C# [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @usr why do you say `Next()` is biased. It is documented to return a number in [0, int.MaxValue) evenly distributed. Do you have evidence to the contrary?

Comment: @zaph `System.Random` is faster and can be seeded, which allows for reproducibility

Comment: If you need reproducibility sure but seeding is a problem, for speed, that is 1. premature optimization and 2. not in evidence.

Comment: @ChaseMedallion look at the source. The mod causes different numbers to have slightly different weights. For example, set max = int.MaxValue - 1 and number 0 will be twice as likely as the others. (I might be off by one).

Comment: @ChaseMedallion Addressing your concern that int.MaxValue-1 might be twice as likely as other values, I looked at a sample of 10^11 numbers generated by rand.Next(). I (well, the computer) counted the occurrences of each of the last 4096 numbers. I got a minimum of 24 occurences, a max of 76, average 46.42, standard deviation 6.818. Int32.MaxValue never occurred. Int32.MaxValue-1 was present 49 times, so it is very probable that it does not occur twice as often. Or my program was wrong (but not quite as probable, hopefully).

Comment: What maximum value did you use? The default might not be broken. Isn't it obvious from the math that some interval of numbers might receive more "coverage"? Int.MaxValue is not evenly divisible into certain bucket sizes (such as Int.MaxValue - 1). IOW your test failed to show the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your analysis is indeed correct. But the defect is one part in two billions *i.e.* `1 / 2^31` so fairly negligible.

The question that one should ask is, is it even detectable ? For example, how many samples *N* does one need to establish the bias with say 99% certainty. From [what I know](http://www.cafemath.fr/mathblog/article.php?page=MonteCarlo.php), *N* > s^2 z^2 / epsilon^2, with

- z = 2.58,
- epsilon = 1 / 2^32 and
- s^2 = p - p^2
- p = 1/2^8 - 1/2^31

this would require 4.77x10^17 samples, a number so large it will hardly be the most obvious defect.

Answer (score -3):

Refer to Knuth vol. 2, 3.2.1.1 Choice of Modulus. You actually want a modulus that is not equal 256; using 256, the lower 4 bits of the resulting byte are considerably less random than are obtained using 257 (p. 12).

257 is also prime, which is convenient to help reduce bias and lengthen the pseudo-random sequence.

Any pseudo-random sequence is, by definition, not truly random. For non-cryptographic applications, what is *unbiased enough*? If in doubt, my recommendation is to sample the generated numbers the way your application is going to draw them and do some statistical analysis. The off-the-shelf random number generators are good enough for many applications, but not necessarily good enough for yours.

Comment: As far as "unbiased enough", my hope would be that derived methods like NextBytes() do not add any bias or non-uniformity on top of what we already have coming out of Next(). As an example, the [Java Random method nextInt(bound)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) states that the outcome will be perfectly random given that the base source of randomness is perfectly random (which it isn't).

Comment: Not quite what the docs say, if you are going to quote a source make the quote accurate. "will" and "would" are substantially different.